# How to limit results of a correlated subquery that uses outer query aliases?

Tags: sql, oracle, correlated-subquery

I'm struggling with a subquery (Oracle 11). Example below is 'invented' for the purpose of the question.

```
SELECT TM.TMID AS TEAM_ID
    ,(SELECT FIRST_NAME || ' ' || LAST_NAME
        FROM PLAYER PL
        WHERE PL.TMID=**TM.TMID**
        ORDER BY AGE) AS OLDEST_PLAYER_NAME
FROM TEAM **TM**
```

Again, this is an invented example. Let's not get into any discussions about naming conventions, normalization or age calculations.

The issue at hand is that the correlated query returns multiple results and I need to pick the first one. If I wrap that correlated query inside another one to do a `select .... where rownum<=1`, I will break the alias reference.

**Please work with my question!**
When trying to help, please state how I can limit results of the subquery above or state that it cannot be done. Do not rewrite this query into some joins because I would not be able to validate that your solution works. If subquery above cannot be limited to a single row, I will evolve complete query into joins myself. This question is strictly about limiting results without breaking the alias reference.

Comment: If you want to write good SQL eventually you will have to start using inline views more than subqueries.  With subqueries, everything is tightly coupled and difficult to debug.  Inline views promote loose coupling, making it easier to break tasks down into independent, manageable chunks.  That won't matter much with your small example.  But when you start building huge queries it's makes a huge difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constraints on answering exclude joins and to continue with the correlated subquery in the select clause.

The options I can think of are

1. Use `MAX()` or `MIN()`
2. Use `row_number ()`  as shown elsewhere
3. Use an ORDER BY then: OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY

E.g

```
( Select MAX(name) from tablex x
   where x.id = outer.id )
```

for a limit of 1 you can do something like the following:

```
select
   customer_id
   , (select cust_last_name 
       from demo_customers c 
       where c.customer_id = o.customer_id
       ORDER BY c.cust_state desc 
       OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
      ) name
from demo_orders o
```

But: in that example there is simply no good reason not to use a join instead which would be far more efficient.

```
select
     o.customer_id
   , c.cust_last_name 
from demo_orders o
inner join demo_customers c 
       on c.customer_id = o.customer_id
```

Comment: Despite the options provided I agree with John Heller that you would benefit by using more robust and better performing approaches. The select clause is performed after the from clause by the way.

Comment: Can't use Order By. At least in SQL Developer I get a`ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis`. `Max()` works. You've answered the question.

Comment: @user6651485  **Brilliant!**  Will `MAX(name)` return the name of the OLDEST player, or the name Zyggy regardless of his age? `LIMIT 1` doesn't exist in Oracle. The only valid answer is "`row_number()` as shown ELSEWHERE". And THIS answer gets "correct answer"!

Answer (score 3):

Something like this may work. You don't need a correlated subquery, you need a join with a properly defined subquery.

Not tested since (well, you know the rest).

```
    select tm.tmid as team_id, x.first_name || ' ' || x.last_name as oldest_player_name
    from   team tm 
           inner join
           (select first_name, last_name, tmid,                           
                       row_number() over (partition by tmid order by age desc) as rn
            from   player)  x
           on tm.tmid = x.tmid 
    where  rn = 1;
```

**Edited**: If you must use a correlated subquery for whatever reason, you can do it like so:

```
SELECT TM.TMID AS TEAM_ID
    ,(SELECT FIRST_NAME || ' ' || LAST_NAME
        FROM 
          (select first_name, last_name, tmid, 
                          row_number() over (partition by tmid order by age desc) rn
           from PLAYER
          )     PL
        WHERE PL.TMID=TM.TMID
        AND rn = 1) AS OLDEST_PLAYER_NAME
FROM TEAM TM
```

The optimizer should be smart enough to see that the innermost subquery is constant (not correlated) and evaluate it only once.